# When is the next moderator election?

Tags: discussion, election

Recently an election took place on Stack Overflow.

1. When is the next moderator election on Ask Ubuntu scheduled?
2. What are the intervals between elections?
3. Where and when can I *participate* in the election (as a candidate)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your questions in numerical sequence:

1. **When is the next moderator election on Ask Ubuntu scheduled?** There is currently (as of March 14th 2024) *no* forthcoming election scheduled for Ask Ubuntu.
2. **What are the intervals between elections?** Elections are not scheduled at regular intervals, they are held when either Moderator numbers are down, workload is heavy, or a combination of these two events. There will usually be some negotiation and discussion between the elected Moderators and the Community Managers on this subject when appropriate.
3. **Where and when can I participate in the election (as a candidate)?** Elections are held here on Meta and you can nominate yourself if you are a community member in good standing with at least 300 reputation.

Bear in mind the work of an elected Moderator on Ask Ubuntu can be difficult at times but it is always, *always* worthwhile work.

Bear in mind as well that this process is [under review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396431/what-would-you-like-to-change-about-the-moderator-election-process) at the moment...

Answer (score 6):

Unlike, say, elections for political representatives, moderator elections are held on Stack Exchange sites not at regular intervals but simply when current moderators or staff decide that one or more additional moderators are needed.

There is no election scheduled at the moment for Ask Ubuntu.

However, *sneak preview alert*, recent backstage discussions suggest an election may be forthcoming some time soon.

Here's what will happen when an election is scheduled:

- A staff member will post here on meta announcing the upcoming election, detailing the timeline and how many mod seats are going to be filled.
- Community members with at least 300 reputation will be invited to stand as a candidate in the election by writing a brief nomination post in the election page. It's really easy.
- Candidates will complete a questionnaire to give the voting community an idea of their style and approach.
- Voting will take place after the nomination period. Community members with at least 150 reputation will be able to vote to elect moderators.
- The successful candidate(s) will <s>undergo a rigorous training regime</s> get started right away.

NB: [All of this may change in the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396924/changing-how-community-leadership-works-on-stack-exchange-a-proposal-and-rough)

Comment: Hey we posted at the same time!! Luckily we seem to have presented roughly the same information, although perhaps we are both wrong :)

Comment: hahaha we even have the same addendum about the review post @andrew.46 XD

Comment: Awwwwwww <3 <3 <3